# Access Document Properties With Filename - SP 2010

Tags: 2010, properties

I have a document library that currently exceeds the list view threshold for all views, so I cannot see any of the library's documents, and I want to edit the properties of a document.  I know the file name of the document from using search, but am unable to access the properties.

Is it possible to construct a link to the properties from the filename?

Options unavailable to me:

- Increase the list view threshold
- Create or modify views